# How do I access similar key, value pairs in a list with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list

```
[{
    "user_id": 1,
    "firstname": "James",
    "lastname": "Katarikawe",
    "email": "jpkatarikawe@gmail.com",
    "password": "$3cur!ty1"
},
    {
    "user_id": 2,
    "firstname": "Paul",
    "lastname": "Kayongo",
    "email": "nserekopaul@gmail.com",
    "password": "rasengan"
}]
```

How do I print out only the email and password values of all items in the list

Comment: `for i in data:
    print(i["email"], i["password"])`

Comment: At least try something and post here if you don't find the answer. Looks like a homework question to me

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in entry_list:
    print(d["email"])
    print(d["password"])
```

Comment: `d["email"]` ,`d["password"]` itself is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{
    "user_id": 1,
    "firstname": "James",
    "lastname": "Katarikawe",
    "email": "jpkatarikawe@gmail.com",
    "password": "$3cur!ty1"
},
    {
    "user_id": 2,
    "firstname": "Paul",
    "lastname": "Kayongo",
    "email": "nserekopaul@gmail.com",
    "password": "rasengan"
}]
for item in l:
    print(item['email'], item['password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for element in mylist:
    print(element['email'])
    print(element['password'])
```

Explanation:

Iterate over the `list` using a variable

```
for element in mylist:
```

print the required values:

```
print(element['email'])
print(element['password'])
```

Comment: @myrdstom: Is this you are expecting ?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Though he is the beginner, he can know one of the solution